# How can we undo stash files, later commit and push again

Tags: git

When I tried `$git pull`, it throws below error, then I continue with `$git stash` and later on tried `$git pull` which was good and got my `git repo` sync with my local directory. Now I would like to undo the `stash` and commit and push those changes again to github repo ! How can I proceed with that ?  Could someone please advise.

```
$ git pull
```

*error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        package.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating b5c5440..a45849e*

```
$ git stash
```

*Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: b5c5440 First commit of ABC classes UI tests*

```
$ git pull
```

Updating b5c5440..a45849e
Fast-forward
 cypress/fixtures/cookies.json   |   2 +-
 cypress/fixtures/tokenData.json |   2 +-
 get-token.js

Comment: `git stash pop`?

Comment: [git stash pop documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt)

Comment: here is neat git cheat sheet. it explains stashing pretty easy.
https://github.com/ayhanyildiz/gitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
git stash pop
```

> Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top of the current working tree state.

Or:

```
git stash apply <stash>
```

> Like pop, but do not remove the state from the stash list.

Note that you can get the `<stash>` id using:

```
git stash list
```

> List the stash entries that you currently have. Each stash entry is listed with its name (e.g. stash@{0} is the latest entry, stash@{1} is the one before, etc.)

Comment: If I perform git pop, then git commit -m “commit the changes” and git push origin master can commit all changes that was stashed earlier to the repo?

Comment: Yes, just stage them  `git add --all`  before committing.

Comment: Check my other answer about how to add and commit changes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58224936/5227526

Comment: I have got an error while doing  `git stash pop`
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        cypress/integration/findClass.spec.js
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.

Comment: You're having changes to the same file in your working directory. What does `git status` display?

Comment: Yes, it show two files changed. But I have lost the stashed files `$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: b5c5440 First commit of ABC classes UI tests`. This was done earlier to `$git pull` to sync with master repo. Now I did what `$ git add --all` and then `$ git commit -m "Add the stashed files"` and then git push to origin master..

Comment: Good for you! To avoid losing your stashed changes, you can use `apply` instead of `pop`.