# How to remove folder on GitHub using Coab?

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I clone my repo where I have some folders and files:

```
!git clone https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/{project}.git
```

then I change current directory:

```
%cd {project}
```

remove a folder:

```
!rm -rf "/content/{project}/sample_data"
```

check status:

```
!git status

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    sample_data/README.md
    deleted:    sample_data/anscombe.json
    deleted:    sample_data/california_housing_test.csv
    deleted:    sample_data/california_housing_train.csv
    deleted:    sample_data/mnist_test.csv
    deleted:    sample_data/mnist_train_small.csv

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

do commit:

```
!git commit -m "Removed all"

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    deleted:    sample_data/README.md
    deleted:    sample_data/anscombe.json
    deleted:    sample_data/california_housing_test.csv
    deleted:    sample_data/california_housing_train.csv
    deleted:    sample_data/mnist_test.csv
    deleted:    sample_data/mnist_train_small.csv

no changes added to commit
```

and push:

```
!git push origin master
```

After that my folder `sample_data` is still in my repo. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can commit you need to stage your changes:

```
git add --all
```

> Stage all the changes

Then run `git commit -m "Your message"` again.

As you can see here after running `git commit -m "Message"`

> no changes added to commit

Git told you that nothing was added to the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are in the default branch:

> git checkout master

.
The rm -r command will recursively remove your folder:

> git rm -r folder-name

.
Commit the change: ...
Push the change to your remote repository